# Performing simple math on two elements of every file in a folder with thousands of .xml files

Tags: xml

I have folder of more files than it is practical to modify manually, and I need to modify a couple of elements to be 60% of their original value.

For example: `<width>1280</width>` and `<height>1280</height>` become `<width>768</width>` and `<height>768</height>`.

I would appreciate some guidance in an approach to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you 'Zeus I see the formatting you fixed, much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="height|width">
   <xsl:copy>{round(. * 0.6)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///the/folder/')">
      <xsl:result-document href="output/{tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kay, admittedly I will do a little digging to learn how to use your solution, since I am not yet familiar with XSLT.

Comment: I understand. I always find it a big effort to get to grips with a new technology. But for anyone working with XML, learning XSLT will make your life a whole lot easier. First point to note is that this solution uses XSLT 3.0: many of the readily available XSLT processors out there never advanced beyond XSLT 1.0.